# Rest call with special characters giving "Event request must have valid JSON body" error in java

Tags: java, json, rest, http-post

I'm trying to make a rest call from java. In request body, I have one field which contains special characters. If I execute this post request from java then its giving me **"Event request must have valid JSON body"** but when I execute same request from postman then I'm getting 200ok response.
Here is the request

```
{
"header": {
    "headerVersion": 1,
    "eventName": "add-incident",
    "ownerId": "owner",
    "appName": "abc",
    "processNetworkId": "networkId",
    "dataspace": "default"
},
"payload": {
    "description": "Arvizturo tukorfurogepa€TM€¢ SchA1⁄4tzenstrasse a€¢",
    "summary": "adding one issue"

}
}
```

This is how I'm executing request in java

```
        String reqBody = "This is a json String cotaining same payload as above mentioned^^";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                        RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()
                ).build();
        
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("Adding URL here");
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(reqBody);
        input.setContentType("application/json);
        postRequest.setEntity(input);
        postRequest.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + "Putting Authorisation Token Here");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Does anyone know what changes i need to do in code to resolve this issue?
Let me know if you want other information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I just made the below change

String finalBody = new String(reqBody.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");

I set the encoding of the HTTP request string to UTF-8. This resolved my issue.

```
    String reqBody = "This is a json String cotaining HTTP request payload";
    String finalBody = new String(reqBody.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                    RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()
            ).build();
    
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("Adding URL here");
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(finalBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    postRequest.setEntity(input);
    postRequest.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + "Putting Authorisation Token Here");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like issue with Character encoding. You are setting `setContentType` to `application/json` but not setting character encoding which eventually defaulted to platform encoding type.

To ensure you are setting `UTF-8` to handle such special characters , change your `StringEntity` initialization with below:

```
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(reqBody,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Also, remove `input.setContentType("application/json");` call, as you don't need it once you use above mentioned constructor. This constructor will take care of using `application/json` as well as setting encoding as `UTF-8`

Comment: I did code changes as per your suggestion but still got the same error.

Comment: `HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                            RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()
                    ).build();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(Constants.URL);

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            postRequest.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + token);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);`